# SharePoint document management

Tags: list, workflow, search, search-results, library

My boss wants our office to create a centralized workspace for some of our documents. It needs to be able to link one document to another based on some criteria.

**Example**

The overarching document would be a grocery list and each food group present in the grocery list would be represented once you click the grocery list button or category.

Then each food group would be linked to a recipe and each recipe would be linked to an evaluation of the meal cooked from that recipe.

The centralized workspace also needs to have a search function to search within the workspace without clicking on each subcategory. My boss wants to be able to see a link from one document to the other. To be able to follow a recipe back to its source ingredients. Is this possible?

Comment: This is definitely possible with the standard out of the box document libraries. You can use metadata (columns) to tag and group documents

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, it is possible, but to broadly answer how exactly would require a significant effort as the process involves adequate use of SharePoint's functionalities. Also, the goal can be achieved in several ways, so I think a rather generic answer is the best I at least can offer. Briefly put you should get familiar with the following topics:

<sup>The following includes a bunch of first-page Google results, so further research with the topics might be recommended.</sup>

- Use **site content types** to have generally available and centrally manageable content types for your Documents/List items, and possible Documents Sets

  - [Create or customize a site content type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-33eeb0b4-51c4-48a2-80d6-a8cd32b7dce1)
- When using site content types, use **site columns** to achieve the same manageability for the fields (=properties) of your items

  - [Create a site column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-site-column-54f6864a-ecbe-4864-b28b-f8a4577d71ab)
- Consider the architecture for you want to store your documents. Do you want to have a multi-level folder-hell? (Don't.) Are you possibly happy with a shallow hierarchy which enhances the use of metadata, searchability and chance of manually hitting your document through natural navigation? (Me too.) Strongly consider using **Document Sets** within your Document Library/Libraries.

  - [Introduction to Document Sets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-c49c246d-31f1-4bfe-afe2-e26698b47e05)
  - Look up for e.g. a blog post where Document Sets are used in practice
- Should the Document be linked to each other with metadata? Possibly. E.g. if your metadata `Ingredient`:`carrot` is linked to a list of recipes, that should be a flexible option. Metadata is made a bit more user-friendly through **managed metadata**

  - [Introduction to managed metadata](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-managed-metadata-a180fa28-6405-4679-9ec3-81d2028c4efc)
- If you want to do a first-class search for your documents, I'd strongly suggest on using **SharePoint's REST API**. After getting the basic returns done, you can implement a search+results -area for e.g. available metadata, title, people associated, ... But if you are after something more simple, SharePoint's library **views** should get you far enough too

  - [Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service)
  - [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)
  - [Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)
  - [REST API reference and samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)
  - [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)